# XSLT: Sorting and Grouping Keys with Multiple Values

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, xslt-1.0, grouping

I have an xml with following content. I want to sort the jobs based on the values of related times.

For each job, there is one related time with two values Num1 and Num2.
I want to sort by these values, so if:
job1 has time1 with values Num1=10, Num2=12 and
job2 has time2 with values Num1=10, Num2=11
the out put should be: job2, job1.
and if job3 has time3 with values Num1=11, Num2=09
the out put should be: job2, job1,job3.
Can I do this with xsl 1.0?

```
<Corp>
 <Type>
   <Class IRI="Jobs"/>
   <Name IRI="Job1"/>
 </Type>
 <Type>
   <Class IRI="Times"/>
   <Name IRI="Time1"/>
 </Type>
 <Relation>
   <RelClass IRI="Job-Time"/>
   <Name IRI="Job1"/>
   <Name IRI="Time1"/>
 </Relation>
 <Data>
   <DataClass IRI="Num1"/>
   <Name IRI="Time1"/>
   <Value>10</Value>
 </Data>
 <Data>
   <DataClass IRI="Num2"/>
   <Name IRI="Time1"/>
   <Value>12</Value>
 </Data>

 <Type>
   <Class IRI="Jobs"/>
   <Name IRI="Job2"/>
 </Type>
 <Type>
   <Class IRI="Times"/>
   <Name IRI="Time2"/>
 </Type>
 <Relation>
   <RelClass IRI="Job-Time"/>
   <Name IRI="Job2"/>
   <Name IRI="Time2"/>
 </Relation>
 <Data>
   <DataClass IRI="Num1"/>
   <Name IRI="Time2"/>
   <Value>10</Value>
 </Data>
 <Data>
   <DataClass IRI="Num2"/>
   <Name IRI="Time2"/>
   <Value>11</Value>
 </Data>    
 </Corp>
```

Comment: You have an element `<Type><Class IRI="Times"/><Name IRI="Time2"/></Type>` which is not used anywhere as all `Data` elements have `<Name IRI="Time1"/>`. So either I don't understand the structure of the input data (you need to explain which elements represent jobs, which times, how they are related) or your input sample is inconsistent.

Comment: Oops, my bad! I edited the xml. All the Times for the second section are Time2 (for Job2). Each job is related to one and only one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you also ask about grouping, as for the cross-referencing and sorting that can be done as

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="rel" match="Relation[RelClass/@IRI = 'Job-Time']" use="Name[1]/@IRI"/>

    <xsl:key name="num1" match="Data[DataClass/@IRI = 'Num1']" use="Name/@IRI"/>
    <xsl:key name="num2" match="Data[DataClass/@IRI = 'Num2']" use="Name/@IRI"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Corp">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Type[Class/@IRI = 'Jobs']">
                <xsl:sort select="key('num1', key('rel', Name/@IRI)/Name[2]/@IRI)/Value" data-type="number"/>
                <xsl:sort select="key('num2', key('rel', Name/@IRI)/Name[2]/@IRI)/Value" data-type="number"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Type[Class/@IRI = 'Jobs']">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```